# Entitlement are not valid

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

My friend send me Build & provision profile OK, 1st I install provision profile than I upload Build on my i pod device , I face this error. Entitlement are not valid?? could you please tell me how can i solve this problem:::: YES UDID is included when generated provision profile?

Answer (score 0):

Have your friend include your device UDID while generating the mobileprovision file?
If not then send your UDID to your friend and ask him to select your UDID as well when generating mobileprovision file

Comment: ask your friend to create .ipa file for installation. if you dont know how to create .ipa file check this link - http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/how-to-create-ipa-file-for-your-iphone-app-xcode-build-and-archive/